# How can I style this list in CSS?

Tags: html, css, list, menu, html-lists

I'd like to know what's the best way to style a list like these:

1.

[image]

---

2.

[image]

That is, with the first `li` element (or the first two, in image #2) being different from the others. The content of both lists is from a database so it needs to be dynamically updatable: everytime I post something new, it's styled differently, then when it goes down it becomes normal. Thanks.

Comment: Look into pseudo-classes like `first-child`, `nth-child`, `first-of-type` & `nth-of-type`

Comment: `li:first-child`, `li:first-child + li`,

Comment: It could be done with `.class:nth-of-type(1)` in css for first two elements.

Comment: Actually `.class:nth-of-type(1)` will not work. You cannot select the nth of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of the various pseudo-classes available.

Codepen Example

**HTML (2 lists)**

```
<nav class="ex-1" role='navigation'>
  <h2>Example 1</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>  

<nav class="ex-2"role='navigation'>
    <h2>Example 2</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
  margin:25px;
  width:250px;
}

li {
  list-style:none;
  background:lightblue;

}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
}

.ex-1 li:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;
}

.ex-1 li:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}

.ex-2 li:nth-of-type(1),
.ex-2 li:nth-of-type(2){
  background:#bada55;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest formatting the data in php or asp first, or Javascript.

If you have divs that contain everything you can style it with GetElementsByClassName('container_name'). This is what it will look like.

```
var DivsWithClassName = document.getElementsByClassName('container_class');

for(var i = 0; i < DivsWithClassName.length; i++) {
    DivsWithClassName.className = DivsWithClassName.className + " otherclass-"+i;
    }
```

What this lets you do is to create a new class for every element in the array meaning that you have one general class as well as unique ones for every div or li element.

So you can have li .container_class img {display: none} and have the exception .otherclass-1 img {display: block}

Or you can go for pseudoclasses as the others have suggested. Personally I would prefer to clean up the output data in php or asp first.